# Canceling order after payment complete

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0

When customer ask cancel order and refund, I refund payment on 3rd party payment admin page

the order status is still processing in magento admin and when I try to cancel , I got

> The order(s) cannot be canceled

I checked the invoice page of the order but there is no button like refund

How can I cancel order after payment complete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any invoiced orders in Magento cannot be "canceled", but they can be "closed". It sounds like you need to issue a "credit memo", which is a refund in Magento.

Comment: There is nothing in 'Credit Memo' tap in the order

Comment: Do you have an invoice or no?

Comment: Invoice is created

Comment: Click on the invoice and see if there's a credit memo button on the top right of the actual invoice page.

Comment: Ah I find 'Refund Offline' button on there! I will try this next time Thank you!

Comment: You can mark this as the answer, :)

Comment: I already tried before but this site say I have to wait more minutes

Comment: There is no option for closed after invoice created

Comment: An `Offline Refund` will not return the money to that person's method of payment without extra action. Be careful on which you choose to make sure you actually return any funds that were captured